# mysql 6.1.11 client to Mysql 8 connection

Tags: mysql, c, ssl, connection

I have a mysql server 8.0.21 running on ubuntu 20.04, on this later i also have a VB  win7 32bi guest.

I'm trying to connect to the Mysql server from guest using c api (specifically 6.1.11 connector as newer MySQL 8 installations no more support win7)

I'm running the following basic program:

```
int main(){
    MYSQL *conn;
    conn = mysql_init (NULL); 
    if(mysql_real_connect ( conn, "169.254.128.100", "myuser","mypass", "my_schema", 3306, NULL,0 )==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    }
    mysql_close ( conn );
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error: "SSL Connection Error: Unknown error number"

The thing is i can connect fine using the ODBC DSN

I also checked the server status & it requires no ssl ("not in use")

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql.h>

static char *host = "localhost";
static char *user = "user";
static char *pass = "password";
static char *db   = "mysql";
static char *socket = NULL;
unsigned int port = 3306;
unsigned int flags = 0;

/*
* brew install mysql-client
* export PATH=/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH
* brew install mysql-connector-c++ (optional)
* gcc -o main $(mysql_config --cflags) main.c $(mysql_config --libs) -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
*
* -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib is required if you get ld: library not found for -lssl error
*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
    
    if (!mysql_real_connect(con, host, user, pass, db, port, socket, flags)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %s (%d)", mysql_error(con), mysql_errno(con));
        exit(1);
    }
    
    printf("Connected\n");
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do this:

```
int sslmode = 1;
mysql_options(&p->mysqlConn, MYSQL_OPT_SSL_MODE, &sslmode);
```